# Broken page redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules

I tried one plugin. It had settings page where I need to select page where I want to present plugin's content. I selected one of my pages - mywebsite.com/page1/ and tested how plugin works.

Then I decided to delete this plugin. And now if i open url mywebsite.com/page1/ - I got redirect to main page.

I tried manually change URL of this page and it works fine. But how can I get mywebsite.com/page1/ to use?

Comment: You should clear page cache and cookies. This will be probable made a 301 redirect and cached by your browser. This don’t account the .htaccess

Comment: the problem is that happen even other browsers - so I think that this plugin changed rewrite rules somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I found solution - I needed to run flush_rules() method at least once to clean cache.

```
//Ensure the $wp_rewrite global is loaded
global $wp_rewrite;
//Call flush_rules() as a method of the $wp_rewrite object
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );
```

Comment: Navigating to the permalinks page will do the same.